# Give an example of a three equation three variable system of linear equations that has no solution. Prove your answer.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This seems very straight forward but I am afraid my answer is too simple or needs more proof:

Let each equation be an equation of a plane. Choose our equations such that the planes are parallel but do not coincide. Their are no points of intersection, thus no solutions to the system. Three such equations are:

$x+y+z=1$,
$x+y+z=2$,
$x+y+z=3$

Am I missing anything?

Thanks

Comment: It is perfect! You could also subtract the the first equation to the second and you would obtain $(x+y+z)-(x+y+z)=2-1 \iff 0=1$ and so there is no solution.

Comment: a simpler example might be something like $x=1$, $x=2$, $x=3$.

Comment: @yoyo that's only one variable though - the question asks for 3.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct and you can see straight away that there are no solutions. You could've done what @Gio did in the comments to reach a contradiction.

I'm going to give another two examples:

$$\begin{align} \begin{cases}x-y-2z=4 \space(1)\\4x-4y-z=2\space(2)
\\-x+y+2z=-3\space(3) \end{cases}\end{align}$$

Then $(1)+(3)$ gives $0=1.$ Contradiction!

$$\begin{align} \begin{cases}6x+2y+4z=4 \space(\cdot)\\3x-3y-z=23\space(\cdot \cdot)
\\3x+y+2z=-24\space(\cdot\cdot\cdot) \end{cases}\end{align}$$

Then $(\cdot)-2\times(\cdot\cdot\cdot)$ gives $0=(6x+2y+4z)-2(3x+y+2z)=4-2(-24)=52$
$\implies0=52$, again a contradiction.